# Is there a way to create a FormComponent with a HTML templet in Apache Wicket

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

I am writing some Forms in Apache Wicket 6 and have come parts of the forms that have the same fields. Is there a way to create a form component with a html Template like a panel would have a html template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you ask for [FormComponentPanel](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/a479020a3c2a52ae8a9ef30b72a3c04eae3011ff/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/FormComponentPanel.java)